# Using "as numeric" function

Tags: r, if-statement, numeric

I am trying to create a new binary variable in my dataset in RStudio using the following code:

```r
leaders$warbefore <- as.numeric(leaders$interwarbefore == '1', leaders$civilwarbefore == '1')
```

`Leaders` is the name of the existing dataset and `warbefore` is the new variable I created.

When I compute the code above, It means that the new binary variable I created,`warbefore`, is equal to 1 only if the variables I selected, `interwarbefore` and `civilwarbefore` are **both** equal to 1.

However I would like to code that `warbefore` is equal to 1 when `interwarbefore` is equal to 1 **OR** when `civilwarbefore` is equal to 1. In other words, both `civilwarbefore` and `interwarbefore` do not have to be necessarily both 1 in order to `warbefore`, the new variable I created, be 1.

How should I add this "OR" possibility? Could someone please help me rephrase the code?
Thanks

Comment: You should add the language into your tags!

Comment: What language are you using? You've asked a code related question without adding a tag for the language you've using, which is far more important than the three other tags you added. Please [edit] your post and add that tag.

Comment: thank you Ken. I am sorry for that. I am using RStudio

Comment: Please type `?Logic` in R or look in the Help for "Logical Operators". What you look for is `|`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```r
leaders$warbefore <- as.numeric(leaders$interwarbefore == 1 | leaders$civilwarbefore == 1)
```

As Piotr K stated, the `|` notes the logical OR.